# Upgrade spree to 1.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm trying to upgrade Spree from 0.7.0 to 1.0.0, I added in my gemfile

```
gem 'spree', '1.0.0'
```

and mounted the routes by adding this in routes.rb

```
Store::Application.routes.draw do
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => "/"
end
```

after that I had override some controllers and model and I added the namespace Spree:: in this way

```
Spree::ProductsController.class_eval do
```

now I'm stuck on this error

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'store_development.spree_product_groups' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `spree_product_groups`
```

and it is totally right cause the table does not exists, but it is named without the spree_ prefix, how can i quickly fix it?
I suppose that some new column or table has been added to the database, how can i check this?
Is there a procedure to upgrade safely spree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you run the new migrations for Spree 1.0?

```
rake railties:install:migrations
rake db:migrate
```

These migrations that'll be copied over will rename your tables correctly.